# How to create a one-time Dataset Copy (no scheduled recurring) using CLI bq command

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to use bash script to make a one-time dataset copy in BigQuery, from `source_dataset_A` to `target_dataset_B`

This operation is easy to do in BigQuery Console, like this
[image]

However, if I use `bq mk --transfer_config` like below, it will create a dataset copy transfer job with a recurring schedule, "every 24 hours".

```
bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=data-project --data_source=cross_region_copy \
  --display_name='one-time-dataset-copy' \
  --target_dataset=target_dataset_B \
  --params='{"source_dataset_id":"source_dataset_A","source_project_id":"source_project","overwrite_destination_table":"true"}' \
```

How could I do a one-time dataset copy in BigQuery?

Answer (score 6):

It took me a while to figure out how to do it, but what it takes is to set the three `schedule` flags in `bq` properly.

> --schedule: Data transfer schedule. If the data source does not support a custom schedule, this should be empty. If empty, the default value for the data source will be used. The specified times are in UTC. Examples of valid format: 1st,3rd monday of month 15:30, every wed,fri of jan,jun 13:15, and first sunday of quarter 00:00.

> --schedule_end_time: Time to stop scheduling transfer runs for the given transfer configuration. If empty, the default value for the end time will be used to schedule runs indefinitely.The format for the time stamp is RFC3339 UTC "Zulu".

> --schedule_start_time: Time to start scheduling transfer runs for the given transfer configuration. If empty, the default value for the start time will be used to start runs immediately.The format for the time stamp is RFC3339 UTC "Zulu".

To make a one-time copy, you would need to set the schedule with proper start and end time that it would only run once.

So you could do this

```
bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=data-project --data_source=cross_region_copy \
  --display_name='one-time-dataset-copy' \
  --target_dataset=target_dataset \
  --params='{"source_dataset_id":"source_dataset","source_project_id":"source_project","overwrite_destination_table":"true"}' \
  --schedule_end_time=$(date -u -d '5 mins' +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)
```

It means to set up a dataset copy transfer job for a schedule of every 24 hours (`--schedule` default), with schedule starting immediately `--schedule_start_time default`, and schedule ending in 5 mins from now ( `--schedule_end_time` ).
By doing that, the transfer job would only trigger one and only one run.

Answer (score 1):

A similar related issue:  You'll find that when you ***do*** want a new query/script or transfer to run at specific times, then by default `bq mk --transfer_config` also runs it immediately on deployment, in addition to the schedule you specify.

To prevent the immediate run of our scheduled queries and transfers, I adapted @Hui Zheng's answer and overrode `--schedule_start_time default` instead of `--schedule_end_time`:

```bash
bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=data-project --data_source=cross_region_copy \
  --display_name='Alerts refresh from Production' \
  --target_dataset=target_dataset \
  --params='{"source_dataset_id":"source_dataset","source_project_id":"source_project","overwrite_destination_table":"true"}' \
  --schedule="every sunday 19:00" \
  --schedule_start_time=$(date -u -d '5 mins' +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)
```

Then you can check the transfer created under Big Query > Scheduled Queries in the Google Cloud Console. There should no longer be a green tick next to it that indicates it has already been run. Instead, a black circle shows that it has no runs (yet), and will only start at the desired next schedule time.

[image]

Comment: very useful answer to a different question.