# Automation shell script to copy big query dataset using transfer service command

Tags: google-bigquery, copy, transfer

I want to write an shell script which copy source datasets into target dataset through transfer command line.

Note: copy should happen at dataset level as we have thousands of datasets in bigquery.

Comment: What is the source of data ?

Comment: source of data will change depends on the underlying tables in dataset. But the main query is about hou to copy dataset using transfer service in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

Project_Id='input your project name'
Location='input your location'
Tar_Data_Set='input you targeted dataset name'

for Data_Set in $(bq ls -n 1000 --project_id=${Project_Id} --location=${Location}| sed -n '3,$p')
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "Input parameter error" && exit 1
do
                
    for Table_Name in  $(bq ls ${Data_Set}| awk '{if(NR>2){print $1}}')
    do
         echo "bq cp -f ${Project_Id}.${Data_Set}.${Table_Name} ${Project_Id}.${Tar_Data_Set}.${Table_Name};"   &>/dev/null 
    done
              
done
```

Here, we assume that it copies tables under **the same** project id.

Comment: Thank You for the response. I have already prepared the automation script using copy command and tested as well. But if you use bq cp commnad  there will be some cons like below.  1. Google will incur more charges when you use bq cp commnad  2. bq cp command will copy table to table. Hence i want to go transfer service in command line to avoid charges and copy direct datasets not at table level.

Comment: Sample Command : bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=[PROJECT_ID] --data_source=[DATA_SOURCE] --target_dataset=[DATASET] --display_name=[NAME] --params='[PARAMETERS]'

Comment: Thanks for sharing the cons which I don't pay attention to that before.

BTW, it seems like have solution in stack overflow :[How to create a one-time Dataset Copy (no scheduled recurring) using CLI bq command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66559395/how-to-create-a-one-time-dataset-copy-no-scheduled-recurring-using-cli-bq-comm)

Comment: Thanks Simon. I need to pass dataset name as a variable to the transfer command.To simplify, first I will extract dataset list using bq ls command and redirect into one file, further I will separate view dataset and table dataset. Now I will run the while loop and inside while loop , ba transfer command will run where the dataset name should be passed as a variable. Hence am preparing automation script to copy N number of datasets to target